# Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'makeIntegralInPlace'

Tags: swift, swift3, cgrect

I had this working prior to Swift 3 (where `frame` is CGRect):

```
extraLightBlurView.frame.makeIntegralInPlace()
```

But it's returning error `Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'makeIntegralInPlace'` in Swift 3. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not available in Swift 3. Use the `integral` property instead:

```
extraLightBlurView.frame = extraLightBlurView.frame.integral
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1456348-integral)

Comment: Not just renamed, it returns a value instead of mutating the given rect. (CGRect has no mutating members at all in Swift 3.)

Comment: Renamed? but it also present in swift 2.0 @jrturton. it is removed(makeIntegralInPlace) in swift 3.0 as Martin R said.

Comment: `extraLightBlurView.frame.integral` returns an CGRect. But my previous method `makeIntegralInPlace` was performing some tasks. What I suppose to do with this new returning value? Do I need to call `makeIntegralInPlace` at all in Swift 3 or there is other way to perform what `makeIntegralInPlace` used to do.

Comment: Updated answer. I did not realise makeIntegralInPlace actually fed back to the frame of the view, I'm glad they changed that.